# How to render ui-routes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-routing, angular-ui-router

[image: index.html]

> ui-routing

This is my  very intial index.html. I am in need to use nested routing. Now as per the docs available. I created this index.html. Barely it have 2 ui-sref but its not even rendering

[image]

What I am missing.Can somebody tell me?
 I am very new to ui-routing.

**Apart from it one very imp to ask?**
Suppose I have url  /albums/hindi where hindi is a partial view is rendered using ng-routes/ng-view but from this level of can I config such that from this level of nesting of url use ui-routing. 
**

> I mean to say can I have ui-view inside ng-view.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide code snippets, **not pictures**, and even better the plunker...

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DoWGHS81DQ196Ia6EG2A?p=preview)

You are almost there, just the way how the ui-sref or href is called is not correct.

So, this could be the adjusted **`index.html`**

```
<html ng-app="routingApp" ng-strict-di>
  <head>
    <title>my app</title>
    <style>ul { padding-left: 0; } li { list-style: none; }</style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head> 

  <body>

      // ui-sref
      <a ui-sref="state1">state1</a>
      <a ui-sref="state1.list">state1.list</a>
      //href
      <a href="#/state1">/state1</a>
      <a href="#/state1/list">/state1/list</a>


      <div ui-view=""></div>
```

And in script.js we can have these states (unchanged)

```
  .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: 'partials/state1.html',
  })
  .state('state1.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: 'partials/state1.list.html',
      controller: 'ListCtrl',
  })
  .state('state1.list.detail', {
      url: "/:title",
      template: '<b>{{$stateParams.title}}</b>',
  })
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DoWGHS81DQ196Ia6EG2A?p=preview)